# AttributeError: module 'discord' has no attribute 'interaction'

Tags: discord.py

discord.py has not the attribute "interaction", which i need for my new discord bot.

This is my code:

```
@bot.tree.command(name="help")
async def help(interaction: discord.interaction):
    await interaction.response.send_message(f"Hey, das ist ein test")
```

I tried "AttributeError: module 'discord' has no attribute 'interaction'"

Answer (score 4):

That would be `discord.Interaction`, not `discord.interaction`. Make sure you are using a capital `I`. [Here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html#interaction) is the link to the relevant API docs.

Answer (score 0):

After reviewing your code, it looks like you're missing a capital `I` in `discord.Interaction`.
However, if it still doesn't work after modifications made, consider looking at the version of discord.py you are using. Maybe it is not the `2.0.0 (minimum)`

And if it is the right version, try using this way of making it:

```py
#imports

intents = discord.Intents.all() # defining intents
intents.members = True

bot = discord.AutoShardedClient(intents = intents, shard_count = 1) # Making a new bot
slash = app_commands.CommandTree(bot) # Declaring commandTree

@slash.command(name = "help")
async def help(interaction: discord.Interaction):
    await interaction.response.send_message(f"Hey, das ist ein test")
```